# Ayuda subida aplicacion a servidor

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, server

tengo un proyecto hecho en Laravel, lo he subido a un servidor gratuito(ihostfull.com) y me da error 500 en absolutamente todas las rutas, excepto la pagina 404 que me carga correctamente, no he subido una aplicación a servidor en mi vida, no se por donde pueden ir los tiros, ¿alguna idea? dejo un par de capturas.
[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Al subir una aplicación de laravel a un servidor compartido se deber realizar algunas cosas.

1. Primero debes asegurarte que el contenido de la carpeta *public* del proyecto de laravel se encuentra en la carpeta public-html del gestor de archivos del servidor (incluyendo todos los archivos sueltos)
2. También te recomiendo crear una carpeta como proyectos o trabajo que es donde irá la carpeta de tu proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Finalmente dentro de tu archivo index.php debes cambiar las siguientes rutas para que apunten a la carpeta de tu proyecto en laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Si, justo lo tengo así,de hecho como comento la pagina 404 me carga cuando introduzco una ruta fallida pero es la unica pagina que me carga..

Comment: Una forma rápida de ver que esta sucediendo es en tu .env colocando app_debug= true y ver si hay algún error intentado entrar a cualquier ruta. Si ya tienes el .env de esta forma el problema se vuelve un poco mas difícil de identificar.